# How to compare two folders in Beyond Compare and then check them into TFS?

Tags: git, tfs

This is a newbie workflow question. I am used to Git and in that SCM, it would be very simple to merge an external folder into my repository and commit and push everything. However, I'm not sure how to do that in TFS. I am not using Visual Studio, what I have is the shell extension from TFS Power Tools and a plugin in Eclipse.

The workflow I would like to emulate in TFS would be like this in Git:

1. Go to my repository at `C:\myproject`
2. Take some other folder, like `C:\myproject-v2.0`
3. Open Beyond Compare and manually merge `myproject-v2.0` into `myproject`.

   - Note: This includes not only file modification but also adding and removing files which is kind of a tougher scenario for TFS, at least it seems.
4. `git commit`
5. `git push`

The really crucial part is step 3 - I need to use an intelligent folder comparison tool, otherwise, it would be quite difficult to merge the folders. I can't work directly in an IDE (Eclipse in my case) which seems to handle some TFS file statuses etc.

When I try to go through the workflow with TFS as a SCM, I end up with "no pending changes" in step 4. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: While @discens reply is absolutely correct, you can also use the built-in "return online" functionality in Team Explorer Everywhere.  Just right click on your Java Project and select "Team > Detect Local Changes".

Comment: Good suggestion, worth upvoting as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between the workflow is whether you are using `Server Workspaces` or `Local Workspaces` in TFS.  Otherwise it's the same workflow.

**Server Workspaces - not deleting files/folders**

1. `Check out` folder you wish to compare
2. Take some other folder, like ....
3. Open Beyond Compare and manually merge
4. `Check In` folder

**Local Workspaces** - TFS 2012 Only

1. Take some other folder,  like...
2. Open Beyond Compare and manually merge
3. `Check In` pending changes.

The crucial difference between these two workflows is whether you need to `Check Out` the folder first.

**Update - workflow if using Server Workspaces and you are deleting files**

Alternatively there is the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).  There is a tool that allows you to sync changes to a folder.  The tool is designed for allowing you to work offline and then sync your changes up afterwards.

`tfpt online`

1. Take some other folder, like ...
2. Open Beyond Compare and manually merge
3. Run `tfpt online` command line tool
4. Check in pending changes.

**Update - Another way if you're using Team Explorer Everywhere - from @Edward-Thomson**

You can also use the built-in "return online" functionality in Team Explorer Everywhere. Just right click on your Java Project and select "Team > Detect Local Changes

Comment: I believe the project uses Server Workspaces (can I choose from the client? or is that dictated by the server?) If I remember correctly, I've tried your approach but when checking in the changes, all of the project files (~1200) were detected as having pending changes, not just the really changed ones (~50). Is that expected? I guess the history dialog would then not be very useful.

Comment: Hi Borek,  Yes that it expected.  The pending changes window will show all checked out files.  However, the server is clever enough to only make changes to the files that actually changed.  When you view the history of the changeset, only the changed files will show.  Regarding Server and Local Workspaces, you can change the default in the settings for the Team Collection.  It is not configurable project by project.  Local Workspaces are only recommended for < 50,000 files too.

Comment: Tried the Service Workspaces workflow but when I merge the two folders and some file happens to be deleted amongst the checked out files, the check in fails with the error "The local item C:\...\somefile.txt no longer exists. So the workflow needs to be more complete I guess - any suggestions?

Comment: Sadly with Server Workspaces there isn't a good workflow for this. The deleted files/folders need to be deleted rather than edited. There isn't a nice way to do this, without deleting them in source control. Local workspaces would fit this workflow much better!

Comment: I've had a bit more of a think and there is a Power Tool that syncs folder changes to TFS.  Ill update the answer.

Comment: Sounds great, will try it out later today. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, `tfpt online` did not detect any deletes so it's not really useful. I'm trying the visual "Folder difference" dialog from Power Tools now, it's also a bit of a mess but at least it seems to list files that are on the server but missing from my local folder. Why TFS makes this so difficult...

Comment: @Borek: use the `/deletes` flag to `tfpt online` to catch deletes.  You probably also want `/adds`.  Using the `/help` option would be beneficial here, probably.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks I've missed that as I thought that the command is just a gateway to the GUI window.